# Build Tools vs Package Manager

Tags: build, package-managers

I am very much confused between these two terms Build tools and Package Manager. According to my current knowledge, Package managers are the ones use to install dependencies required for the code to execute while Build tools are used to Package the code plus dependencies into single file i.e. building the code. Building our application will enable to make it production ready.
Am I right???

Answer (score 2):

Short answer

- Build systems/tools manage your compilation requirements.
- Package managers/tools manager your library requirements.
- A build tool may have integrated package management.

For example, in both C++ and Java you can directly call the compiler and provide all the include, source and library paths manually or you can use a build system (make/cmake... for c++, maven/gradle/ant... for java).

When you link external libraries with your build system it will do its best to find them in its search path, and will link with the first version that meets its requirements or tell you that it couldn't find it. Adding libraries manually is fairly easy, but sometimes each library you add will require another library with it.

A package manager would make sure that your libraries are downloaded, are the right version, and all the libraries they depend on are downloaded. some examples are maven and gradle which have integrated package managment for java, and conan is a fairly popular option to combine with cmake.

So ideally you would use both, but it can be more work setting them up than you save not doing things manually. It depends on your programming language, if you need multiple versions of something, and your OS.